# How do i iterate to get text from webelement and verify

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to python selenium. Could you please tell me how to iterate through each webelement and extract the text and validate it. For example I have attached the screenshot

```
for the Below code:

<div class="portlet light bordered hasdesc" id="FuncDescPortlet">
<div class="row">
<span class="caption-subject sbold">SUM:</span>   
<span class="caption-subject">Sums up all the given numbers.</span>   
<span class="caption-subject sbold" style="margin-left: 30px;">Examples:</span>   
<span class="caption-subject">SUM(2, 3, 8) =&gt; 13</span></div>    


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr52P.png
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and update with code trial what you have done so far.

Comment: Wht is the expected output?

Comment: I want to iterate through a webelements list and return the text from each of the span tag